# KMango: update collection with col.updateOne / col.updateMany

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

> I am using [KMongo](http://litote.org/kmongo/#start_coding) to connect my Kotlin app with MongoDB

I am trying to update only one document which following expression

```
mongoCollection.updateOne("""{name: "John"}""", """{name: "Adam"}""", UpdateOptions())
```

<s>Strangely enough this is calling `MongoCollection.updateOne(Bson target, Bson update, UpateOption option)`</s>

and I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name name
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use quotes on fields names? (`mongoCollection.updateOne("""{"name": "John"}""", """{"name": "Adam"}""", UpdateOptions())`)

Comment: Yep doesn't work